# Bearer Code returning HTTP 400 error for Twitter Search API V1.1

Tags: java, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement the Twitter Search API V1.1

Please correct me if I am wrong.
I performed the below mentioned steps :

```
Step 1) Created an App in Twitter.
 So I got the TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY and TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRETCODE.

Step 2) I encoded the concatenation of the above keys separated by ":" with the base UTF-8.

Step3 ) Get the bearer token with the above generated code.

Step4 ) Use the bearer code to get the Tweets on the relevance of a keyword.
```

I am stuck in Step 3,

where in I am getting the Response as::

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.crm.socialCRM.action.TwitterIntegration.requestBearerToken(TwitterIntegration.java:74)
    at com.tcs.crm.socialCRM.action.TwitterIntegration.getStatusSearch(TwitterIntegration.java:27)
    at com.tcs.crm.socialCRM.action.TwitterIntegration.main(TwitterIntegration.java:103)
```

My code is ::

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            PrintWriter outWriter = null; 
            BufferedReader serverResponse = null;

            try 
            {
                URL url = new URL(endPointUrl); 
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true); 
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
                connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Search Tweets");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"); 
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "29");
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoOutput( true );


                logger.info("Point 1");

                //CREATE A WRITER FOR OUTPUT  
                outWriter = new PrintWriter( connection.getOutputStream() );  

                logger.info("Point 2");

                //SEND PARAMETERS  
                outWriter.println( "grant_type=client_credentials" );  
                outWriter.flush();  
                outWriter.close();  

                logger.info("Point 3");
                //RESPONSE STREAM  
                serverResponse = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream() ) );  

                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(serverResponse);


                logger.info("The return string is "+obj.toString());
                return  obj.toString();
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the bearer token from Twitter. Also I test your same code and I received the error 403. After that I was creating my custom method to obtain the bearer token from twitter and I got the solution.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY";
    String consumer_secret="YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET";  

    // Following the format of the  RFC 1738
    consumer_key=URLEncoder.encode(consumer_key, "UTF-8");
    consumer_secret=URLEncoder.encode(consumer_secret,"UTF-8");

    String authorization_header_string=consumer_key+":"+consumer_secret;         
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(authorization_header_string.getBytes());


    String encodedString = new String(encoded); //converting byte to string

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization","Basic " + encodedString);

    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter dev doc tells to give the "Content-Length":

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

(see at "Example Result" below "Step 2: Obtain a bearer token")

However, in my case (with PHP), **it works only if I remove "Content-Length"**.

Comment: + 1 for the reference provided. Will go through the link. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather late, but i found that the following worked for me (thanks @jctd_BDyn for the code to encode the key and secret for basic auth):

```
private String createBasicAuth() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY";
    String consumer_secret="YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET";  

    // Following the format of the  RFC 1738
    consumer_key=URLEncoder.encode(consumer_key, "UTF-8");
    consumer_secret=URLEncoder.encode(consumer_secret,"UTF-8");

    String authorization_header_string=consumer_key+":"+consumer_secret;         
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(authorization_header_string.getBytes());

    return new String(encoded); //converting byte to string
}

private HttpURLConnection createBearerTokenConnection() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + createBasicAuth());
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    String formData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
    byte[] formDataInBytes = formData.getBytes("UTF-8");
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(formDataInBytes);
    os.close();
    log.info("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + bearerTokenUrl);
    return connection;
}

public Optional<BearerToken> getBearerToken() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = createBearerTokenConnection();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        log.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        if (responseCode == 200) {
            // Transforming from JSON string to POJO
            return transformer.toBearerToken(response.toString());
        } else {
            log.error("Unexpected response code with response " + response.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(String.format("IO exception on POST to %s", bearerTokenUrl), e);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```